# Use iPhone's multitasking music controls in an app

Tags: ios, multitasking, background-music

I've searched the Internet for a while to try and find an answer to this. If you open up the multitasking bar and swipe to the left there are music controls that can be used by whatever app is playing music (ie Music, Pandora, etc.). I have not yet discovered a way to use these in my own music playing application. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Listings/Classes_MainViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Classes_MainViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) in the Apple API docs examples. It's basically what you want, a small audio player that interfaces with iTunes, lets you pick songs from the library and behaves much like the standard music player, including the music controls callbacks.

Comment: It seems like that is only available for MPMediaPlayer? I could be wrong. Is there anything for that would work for AVAudioPlayer and AVPlayer?

Comment: From what I understand, all the functionality for this is contained in MediaPlayer.framework, so you're probably right. I understand that a lot of audio apps use MPMediaPlayer for playing back audio that is expected to require user control from time to time (pause, forward, etc). AVAudioPlayer, etc seem to be used for more integrated audio needs (ie game music, etc).